# PHPMailer - Sending multiple emails to addresses stored in the mySQL database

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following snippet where I'm trying to send e-mails to multiple addresses.

```
$recipients = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
    $recipients[] = $row;
}

$recipients = array(
   'user_1@domain.com' => 'user_1_name',
   'user_2@domain.com' => 'user_2_name',
);

foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
   $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
}
```

I need to get the email addresses array dynamically filled with the content from the database and tried this.

```
$recipients[] = array(
    $row1['email'] => $row1['name']
    );
```

I'm getting the following error so I know I haven't got the array correctly. Appreciate your thoughts on what have I got wrong in there.

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /Applications/XAMPP...

**EDIT**

PHPMailer also triggers the below error, which I understand since the array I'm trying to dynamically populate isn't getting any of the email addresses from the database.

> Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: *"I'm getting the following error"* - Which is what?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner was editing while you comment!

Comment: *"Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string"* - Where is that function?

Comment: Thats in class.phpmailer.php, which is a class in the PHPMailer. It is triggered I sense because of an error in the array.

Comment: The Warning message is generated from the class.phpmailer.php file which is class in the PHPMail documentation. I'm not brave enough to mess with given classes with PHPMailer and it's just an include. Do you see an error on the way I've created the array?

Comment: see the answer(s); I can't do much without knowing which animal(s) we're dealing with here.

Comment: Send Multiple Emails .... because of GDPR if nothing else

Comment: You could improve the question if you told us What columns you selected and are therefore in the `$row` variable

Comment: `$recipients[$row1['email']] = $row1['name'];` But I doubt you can use an email address as a key name.

Comment: Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: @Synchro Yeah that's helpful mate!

Comment: Welcome to my world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get address

```
$recipients = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
     $mail->addRecipent($row['email'], $row['name']);
}
```

p.s. better use `for`

Comment: How do you know those columns are in the SELECT and therefore available in `$row`

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I loock in question

Comment: Well I think no one would land here without having a SELECT of course. I think without me going around the mulberry bush, I can adapt this suggestion from @Naumov

Comment: _Small Note_ Bcc addresses are not invisible (GDPR)

Comment: @Naumov what does `$first` doing here?

Comment: BCCs are invisible to recipients, but they appear in SMTP traffic (otherwise they wouldn't work).

Comment: @MohanWijesena you can don't use `$first` I use this variable, because don't right translate error message in question. sorry for my English.